# Executing a queue of handlers that return a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, promise

I have a queue of handlers that I need to execute in order of insertion then wait for each one to return a resolved promise before executing the next in line.

I have decided to use a recursive function to shift a handler out of the queue then execute it. When the handler resolves its promise the function then calls itself recursively until the queue is empty.

```
var executeHandler = function(handlers, instance){
    var handler, cb = function(){
        return executeHandler(handlers, instance);
    };

    if(handlers.length){
        handler = handlers.shift();
        return handler($q, instance).then(cb);
    }
};
```

This is an adequate solution. However I am unsure this is an ideal solution. When stepping through this function it is very difficult to follow.

Is there a more optimal way to achieve this? More importantly an easier to grasp solution?

Comment: Maybe you want to look into `$q.all`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: The way I've seen is to use the promise returned by `then()` to chain the promises, is there a reason you put them into an array?  Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: @elclanrs `$q.all` was how I originally had it structured. However it just resolves upon an array of promises all being resolved or rejected. I need each function(i.e. handler) to wait for the previous one to have resolved before calling the next.

Comment: @Jason Goemaat The reason for the array is that the user of this API can register these handlers to listen to a certain event, so there could be 1 handler or 20. Essentially I need to execute each handler in the order they were registered. However since the handlers are intended to modify a single instance of an object. It is necessary to wait for each to have completed its work with the current instance before moving on to the next. Hopefully that clarifies the scenario.

Comment: Async stuff is inherently difficult to step through and I've not seen any debugging tools or coding styles that really make it any easier.  You end up just having to set breakpoints because you just can't step through async stuff line by line.  By it's very nature, it finishes executing what needs to be done right now and then calls some callback later which doesn't lend itself to step-by-step debugging.  What you have seems reasonable to me.  You could also use `.reduce()` to immediately chain them all together, but that doesn't help any with debugging.

Comment: FYI, this question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com since you have working code and are asking for a more ideal solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 You have a good point the very nature of it makes it difficult to step through the code, and another good point that this should probably be posted on codereview. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You have (a variant of) the socalled "anti-pattern" given [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) under the title "The Collection Kerfuffle". For series execution, you need (a variant of) the second recommended pattern under that heading (viz jfriend00's `.reduce` suggestion). The given example iterates through an array of items passing each (and the previous result) to a fixed function. Your problem differs only in that it iterates through an array of functions passing to each a fixed item.

Comment: I would guess that the `.reduce` pattern is no easier to step through than a recursive solution, but it is rapidly becoming the *de facto* pattern for async iteration of an array, therefore (in time) more recognisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, like [jfriend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) and [Roamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888) suggested - you don't have to actually implement recursion since promises already chain. Let's recap:

- A promise represents an eventual value of an operation.
- `.then` represents a semicolon or line drop in your code, it's an abstraction on the notion of flow control and sequencing itself. It's actually very close to a monad [bind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).
- Therefore when we translate flow control to promises, we replace semicolons with `then`s.

Let's start with a synchronous version

```
function each(handlers, instance){
    // here the function flow control starts
    handlers.forEach(function(handler){ // iterate all handlers
         handler(instance); // call the handler
    }); // in the promises version we'll iterate in advance since it's simpler
    return; // when the function returns it's done
}
```

Now, how do we translate that to promise code?

- The flow control starting is represented by an empty resolved promise: `$q.when`
- The forEach loop is the same, but we'll iterate the array and chain function executions synchronously since it's simpler in this case.
- The `handler()` will be "wait for the previous handler to finish and then run this one".
- The return will return the chained promise so we'll know when we're done.

This should look something like:

```
function each(handlers, instance){
    var p = $q.when();
    handlers.forEach(function(handler){ 
        p = p.then(function(){ return handler(instance); });
    });
    return p;
}
```

The advantage here is that the flow is in a loop rather than recursion which is easier to follow for some people, basically instead of implementing our own 'next' logic we have delegated that responsibility to promises. Here is what jfriend and roamer mean by `reduce`:

```
function each(handlers, instance){
    return handlers.reduce(function(p, next){ 
        return p.then(function(){ return next(instance); });
    }, $q.when());
}
```

This sort of thing (aggregating an array into a single value) is exactly what reduce is for which is why it fits so naturally.

While the for loop solution arguably is not easier to step through with a debugger I think it's a lot easier to grasp than the explicit recursion and book-keeping of your first solution.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough and concise answer. I would like to use the reduce pattern. However is there a way to "break" out of the reduce iteration?

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo there is no `break`, you can throw an error inside a `then` and catch the rejection (Since promises are throw safe). Or you can return a dummy and iterate the collection without actually appending to it.